# Динамический RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

Вообщем есть скролл, в нем есть другие элементы,а также 7 кнопок, которые, при внешних условиях, то включенные, то нет.
Как я вижу картину: при нажатии на кнопку мне открывает от или иной Recycler, даже нашел реализацию статической высоты для него ([тык](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083091/recyclerview-inside-scrollview-is-not-working)). И все бы было отлично, если бы не элементы этого RecyclerView, они состоят из двух частей: при клике на первую часть, вторая появляется, при еще одном нажатии, вторая часть исчезает, но когда она появляется, размер Recycler'a не изменяется. Уже не знаю как реализовать это, чтоб динамически увеличивался или уменьшался высота Recycler, может кто подскажет, что делать?
Просто тут не получится просто так избавиться от скрола...

Comment: Вы случайно не экран настроек делаете?

Comment: Нет) но что-то близкое по значению

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем, где находится RV пихаем метод

```
public static void reSizeRVPlus(int i){
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) rv.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = rv.getHeight() + i;
        rv.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

и там, где нужно, вызываем(У меня, прям из адаптера)

```
CLASS.reSizeRVPlus(i);
```

И когда надо обратно уменьшить, то отнимаем переменную `i`

Answer (score 1):

Вот с [этим LayoutManager'ом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649406/nested-recycler-view-height-doesnt-wrap-its-content/28510031#28510031) Вы сможете задать для RecyclerView высоту wrap_content и пихать его в ScrollView. Однако Вы бы описали что Вам мешает избавиться от скрола? Может от него всё таки не так сложно избавиться как Вам кажется, а помещать списки внутрь скролов стоит только если уж совсем никак без этого. Мне такое непотребство пришлось реализовывать только когда дизайнер решил впихнуть в одну прокручиваемую область WebView и пару списков одновременно, и это бы ещё можно было сделать в одном RecyclerView, но WebView должен был быть в отдельном фрагменте и иногда переключаться на другой фрагмент, так же находящийся внутри скрола...

Comment: Нет, я находил этот урок, там не предусмотрено то, что элемент в Recycler`e может изменять свой размер,как и у нас в приложении.) но спасибо, за ответ.

Comment: как это не предусмотрено, там как раз размер перерасчитывается при каждом изменении чилдов

Comment: Я ставил этот класс, к примеру, у чилда стоит visibility(GONE), а когда я присвою ему визибл, то размер РВ остается таким же, как и был.

Comment: Вот, сделал ответ)